# C++ wrapping overloaded functions

Tags: c++, overloading

I want to create a wrap for a bunch of overloaded functions

```
void print(int i);
void print(long i);
void print(char* s);
...

void myPrint(int x, int y, ??? toPrint){
    moveTo(x,y);
    print(toPrint);
}
```

How can I do it? Is it possible to go without templates?

Comment: What's wrong with templates?

Comment: That's a classic example of a template function.  Is there a reason you want to forgo that language feature?  Can `toPrint` be any data type **at all**, or just `int`, `long`, and `char`?

Comment: I'm coding for a microcontroller(Arduino), template doesn't seem to be a default feature...

Comment: Can't you make the argument global and then use it in your function myPrint() with out having to receive it through parameter's list?

Comment: @Arslan Sorry, forgot to mention it, the function is actually a class method so globals wouldn't do very well :) Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you **cannot use templates**, you can take the same approach with `myPrint` that you did with `print`.

```
void myPrint(int x, int y, int toPrint){
    moveTo(x,y);
    print(toPrint);
}

void myPrint(int x, int y, long toPrint){
    moveTo(x,y);
    print(toPrint);
}

void myPrint(int x, int y, char* toPrint){
    moveTo(x,y);
    print(toPrint);
}
```

Since you're doing embedded coding, you could also excuse yourself for using a macro.

```
#define MYPRINT( x, y, toPrint ) \
    do {                         \
        moveTo(x,y);             \
        print(toPrint);          \
    } while(false)
```

Comment: Thanks @Drew, this seems to be the coolest! :) But can you do it without the do...while(false)?

Comment: @XunYang Happy to help!  You can omit the do/while if you're careful.  This link explains why I am using it.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154136

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could write three individual wrappers. It's equivalent to what the template would produce (i.e. a bit of code bloat).

```
void myPrint(int x, int y, int toPrint) {
    moveTo(x,y);
    print(toPrint);
}

void myPrint(int x, int y, long toPrint) {
    moveTo(x,y);
    print(toPrint);
}

void myPrint(int x, int y, char *toPrint) {
    moveTo(x,y);
    print(toPrint);
}
```

I don't necessarily recommend this, since code-hiding macros are greatly frowned upon these days, but you could use a preprocessor macro as a template replacement.

```
#define DEFINE_MY_PRINT(Type)                  \
    void myPrint(int x, int y, Type toPrint) { \
        moveTo(x,y);                           \
        print(toPrint);                        \
    }

DEFINE_MY_PRINT(int)
DEFINE_MY_PRINT(long)
DEFINE_MY_PRINT(char *)
```

Answer (score 1):

Templates would be preferred, but you can (ab)use the preprocessor:

```
#define MY_PRINT(T) void myPrint(int x, int y, T toPrint) \
{ \
    moveTo(x,y); \
    print(toPrint); \
}

MY_PRINT(int)
MY_PRINT(long)
MY_PRINT(char*)
```